# Prove if $AB=A$, then $1 ∈ B$ or $-1 ∈ B$.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

> Let $A$ and $B$ be any subsets of integers and define: $AB= \{ab: a \in A, b \in B \}$
>
> Suppose $A$ is the set of even integers. Prove that if $AB=A$, then $1 \in B$ or $-1 \in B$.  hint: You may start by noting that $2 \in AB$,
> explain why, and continue from here.

My thoughts are if $AB=A$, then $AB \subseteq A$ and $A \subseteq AB$. $A$ is the set of even integers. We can start with $2$. $2 \in A$. Since $AB=A$, $2 \in AB$. According to the definition of $AB= \{ab: a \in A, b \in B \}$, $2$ can be written as a product of an even number and an integer. $2$ is a product of $2$ and $1$. In this case, $2$ is the even integer, $2 \in A$ and $1 \in B$. Therefore, I have proved that $1 \in B$.

My question is do I need a more general case like let $x \in A, x=2n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ to prove this question?

Comment: The general case requires $A$ to have a non-zero element.

Comment: “$2$ is a product of $2$ and $1.$ “ That doesn’t prove $1\in B.$ Indeed, $1$ might not be in $B.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews why 1 might not be in B? I don't really understand.

Comment: If $B=\{-1\}$ then $AB=A.$ So it is not always true that $1\in B.$

Comment: The only ways to write $2=xy$ with $x \in 2\mathbb{Z}$ and $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ are $2=(2)(1)$ and $2=(-2)(-1)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Then how should I prove this?

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang so is this able to show $1 \in B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is false if $A= \{ 0 \}$, so we'll assume that's not the case.

Let $n \in A$ be an element of $A$ with smallest absolute value among non-zero elements of $A$.  Then $\vert b \vert \gt 1 \Rightarrow \vert ab \vert \gt \vert a \vert \geq \vert n \vert \Rightarrow ab \neq n$, and $b=0 \Rightarrow ab=0 \neq n$.  Thus, if $n \in AB, \exists~b \in B~(\vert b \vert = 1).$

Comment: The question states $A=2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @YiFan My proof works for arbitrary $A\in \mathscr P(\Bbb Z) \setminus \{ \{ 0 \} \}$, including $A = 2 \Bbb Z$.